# Where do i see what queries have been executed

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, logging

How do i see a log of all the queries that have been executed in my app? im using classic eclipse. in the logcat i cant see any queries that have occurred while my app has been running.

Where do i see this?  ive looked at the log and i do not see any queries or anything in there...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you logging anything manually (i.e. with some code to output to the log)?

Comment: what do you mean queries? You can always do a `Log.i("some event", "this is shown in logcat");` check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries are not logged automatically.  You will need to manually log them with calls to `Log.d()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to see queries performed by your application automatically, but it would probably be a good idea to use the Log class and write debug log entries when you perform a query, so that they get registered there, with a tag defined by you which you can use to easily filter these messages in the log cat console.